# Is it an accessibility problem to have multiple footer elements on a single page?

Tags: html, accessibility

Currently application is having multiple footer elements. it is getting populated by using sitecore module on single page. Here the screen reader is narrating the 5 footer regions on the page

Q1: Is that fine to have multiple footer elements on the code?

Q2: Can we differentiate with aria-label on each footer elements?

#Accessibility#footer
[Code example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRRd0.png)

want to know Can we use multiple footers with aria-label?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and see the [help] page on asking a good question for info on improving your question here. We need to see your code in the question, not as an image, for starters. You also should focus on one question, not multiple.

Answer (score 1):

While it doesn't directly address accessibility, the [MDN footer element docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/footer) give a good hint:

> The `<footer>` HTML element represents a footer for its nearest ancestor
> [sectioning content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#sectioning_content) or [sectioning root](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Heading_Elements#sectioning_root) element. A `<footer>` typically
> contains information about the author of the section, copyright data
> or links to related documents.

This strongly implies that footers are *contextual*, and that there's no issue with having multiple in the page, assuming otherwise good document structure.

Regarding differentiation, see above. Good document structure will inherently associate a footer with its related content by including both in a container element such as a [section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/section) or [article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/article). If for some reason that doesn't suit, the [`aria-describedby`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Attributes/aria-describedby) attribute could be implemented. Neither [`aria-label`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Attributes/aria-label) nor [`aria-labelledby`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Attributes/aria-labelledby) attributes seem appropriate here as this is a need for *association*, not labelling.

Note that it would be a misuse of the footer element to use it simply for design purposes. If your footer merely contains design elements or content not pertinent to the adjacent page or section, a div might be a better choice.